i18next-parser extract plain html/text nodes without custom componentes
I want to extract plain text nodes from react components, just detect it .. add it to file. without using any custom components or so.
currently i thought that's the default behavior of i18next-parser, but found out after 5 hours of configs and custom scripts, that this isn't possible by it,
example expectations
<Button variant="white" size="base" onClick={handleClose}>
    Cancel // i'd like to extract this without wrapping it in a Trans component
</Button>
<p>
 This text should be extractable, it's a normal text node
</p>

is this even possible, workaround?
if it's not possible then what's the differance between this package and i18next-scanner!
Adding options to jsx lexer
     lexers: {
                    js: [
                        {
                            lexer: 'JsxLexer',
                            functions: ['t', 't.rich'], // Array of functions to match
                            transKeepBasicHtmlNodesFor: ['p'],
                            transSupportBasicHtmlNodes: true,
                            componentFunctions:[p]
                        },
                    ],
                },

